# Please provide a full guide to mining with AlethZero?

Tags: alethzero

I am new to mining and would like a start to finish, simple guide to use ALethZero to mine Ether.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are new and posting the question now, Then you should also know that https://github.com/ethereum/alethzero is going to be dead soon. Please start using [Mix](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE).

I believe you want to learn developing application around blockchain and ethereum protocol/platform.If not then you would not need Alethzero , you would use the usual go-ehtereum client to mine.

Comment: Mix isn't a miner but a contract ide

Answer (score 1):

AlethZero is deprecated and won't be part of ethereum package soon. If you want to mine, you'd better use something like ethminer or qtminer.

If you want to mine some test ether to develop contracts, use Mix IDE and mine some test ether or use ethereum development mock like testrpc which I recommend.